# Anidar objetos tablas relacionadas Django API REST Framework

Tags: python, django, postgresql, djangorestframework

Tengo 3 tablas relacionadas, 1 -> 2 -> 3 ahora bien con MySQL haríamos `inner join` de las tablas y listo ya podríamos filtrar por campos de las 3, la cosa es que con la API REST quisiera que me anidara todos los elementos de la 3 relacionados con la 2 relacionados a la vez con la 1 y yo solo llamando la primera.

La cosa es que consigo que me anide todas las tablas relacionadas con la 1, pero todas las que estén relacionadas con las que están relacionadas con la 1 no puedo acceder a ellas ni que me anide.

Es decir que yo puedo hacer un:

```
Model.object.filter(2__2_name="Antonio")
```

Funciona, pero quisiera poder hacer:

```
Model.object.filter(2__2_name="Antonio", 3__3_tipo="Casa")
```

Y que me devuelva todo anidado la 1 la 2 y la 3, solo llamando la 1.

Como debo relacionar los `serializers` o como filtrar las `views` para que pueda acceder al tercer nivel?

No sé si me explico muy claramente pero por poner un ejemplo:

Quisiera poder filtrar con la API REST de Django que me devuelva todas las preguntas y respuestas de una marca y un idioma en concreto y no sé como debo relacionar los `serializers` o sacar dicha información en la `view` o `viewset`.

El filtrado de una tabla sola o una que tiene relación directa no hay problema, pero cuando ya tengo que cruzar tanto me lío.

¿Como debo hacerlo? Django Multiple Models, `ModelViewset`, `ViewsetMixin` o como? La documentación no es lo suficientemente clara a mi parecer.

Comment: @castellbot En el caso que me expones imagino que ambas tablas están relacionadas entre si, la cosa es que en mi caso no tengo porque tener relacionada la tabla 1 con la 3, pero si que tengo relacionada la 2 con la 3 y la 1 con la 2, y he probado tu ejemplo y solo me saca los resultados de tablas directamente relacionadas. Pero no funciona en el caso que te acabo de exponer.... Sabes como podría hacerlo en mi caso?

Answer (score 2):

Me imagino que quieres mostrar información de las 3 tablas relacionadas sólo con llamar a la de menor jerarquía. En mi caso tengo Usuario > Perfil > Doctor y lo que hago es lo siguiente:

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_full_name(self, obj):
        return '%s %s' % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'full_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'role', 'code', 'telephone', 'telephone2')

class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('id', 'profile', 'code', 'specialities', 'status')
```

Ahora sólo queda agregar DoctorSerializer a la vista y filtrar solo con usar la tabla Doctor. Con esto ya se puede mostrar la información de las 3 tablas relacionadas, el resultado sería:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "profile": {
            "id": 4,
            "user": {
                "id": 3,
                "username": "rmorales",
                "full_name": "Ricardo Morales",
                "first_name": "Ricardo",
                "last_name": "Morales",
                "email": "rmorales@company.com",
                "profile": 4
            },
            "role": 1,
            "code": "1234 44444 1234",
            "telephone": "3000",
            "telephone2": "4000"
        },
        "code": "12123",
        "specialities": [],
        "status": 1
    }
]
```

Sólo queda sustituir tus tablas. Puedes ver la info en la [documentación](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) oficial.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera sencilla seria usar `depth` en el serializer:

```
class BrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'languages', 'created')
        depth = 3
```